# Pymongo $in query throws error unhashable type list

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, python-3.5

I am using pymongo to query some users like this

```
mongo_client = MongoClient("my_url")
mongoDb = mongo_client["My_db"]  
no_list = [1,2,3] 
all_active_users = user_profile_coll.find({"active": True, "regNo": {"$in", no_list}})
```

I am getting this error when I run my tests.

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Why would this be happening. I am using Python 3.5 and Mongo 3.2 and Pymongo 3.4

Comment: You have a typo in there. `{'$in': [1,2]}` Also don't assign value to  a builtins name as you did *`list = [1, 2, 3]`*

Comment: my bad. just updated. I want to pass the list only. I just showed `list=[1,2,3]` as an example.

Comment: Read my comment carefully. You got the `$in` syntax wrong

Comment: I have been helped by @styvane's comment more than once, but I have also been confused each time.  To be explicit, there is a comma in the dictionary object where there should be a colon.  `{'$in': l}` is right, `{'$in', l}` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was just a typo. Thanks to @Styvane for pointing it out.

```
all_active_users = user_profile_coll.find({'active': True,'regNo': {'$in': no_list}})
```

This worked.